# Moving hosting from godaddy to heroku - need a CNAME for myapp.herokuapp.com, should I remove the A record?

Tags: domain-name-system, cname-record, godaddy, heroku

I've moved my web site hosting from godaddy to heroku. In DNS, I know I need a CNAME record for myapp.herokuapp.com; but what do I do with the A record? Seems like I need that for smtp, as the smtp records use @?

Answer (score 0):

You can't have concurrent CNAME and A records for the same name.

Mail is handled by the MX entry on the root domain, that's unaffected.

If you have subdomains currently CNAME'd to @, just CNAME them to a new name, which then points to the original IP.

This may also be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16022324/how-to-setup-dns-for-an-apex-domain-no-www-pointing-to-a-heroku-app